# Is there a simple way to analyze the dataset within a datalist?

Tags: r, datalist

I have a datalist that contains 100+ dataset. Each dataset looks like:

```
Variable: 'M''M''M''M'...'I''I''I''I''I'

Data1 :  0.88 2.1 1.2 ...

Data2 :  2.6  2.5 1.8...

...

Data89: 3.6 4.5 6.2...

Group_sample: 'M01'M02''M03'...'I01''I02''I03'...

etc.
```

[image]

If I want to see the amount of the M or I and the average of all data of the variable M or I, which code should I use?

Answer (score 0):

We could use `summarise_at` after grouping by 'Variable'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Variable) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(starts_with('data')), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I tried and an error message apear: 
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") :  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: calculate one dataset of the DataList, could use:
- aggregate(Group1[, 3:37], by=list(Group1$variable), FUN = mean).
Is there a way to repeat this code for all other dataset?

Comment: @starter1128. Can you show the `str(df1)`.  I assumed that 'Variable' is a regular column

Comment: The "df1" is a datalist containing 50+ datasets. stf(DataList):
"$ 1:'data.frame': 1148 obs. of  80 variables:
  ..$ Variable                : chr [1:1148] "M" "M" "M" "M" ...
  ..$ sample_group      : chr [1:1148] "S01" "S01" "S02" "S02" ...
  ..$ data1                    : num [1:1148] 2.21 0.881 0.881 1.098 1.062 ...
  ..$ data2                   : num [1:1148] 1.996 0.881 0.881 0.881 1.67 ...
  ..$ data3                    : num [1:1148] 2.499 0.881 0.881 1.838 2.219 ...
       ......"
"$ 2:'data.frame': 1246 obs. of  80 variables:
       ...."
etc.